# Should you kill isolate at the end of execution?

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want a clarification since I rarely see someone kill their spawned **isolate** at the end of execution, let's say that I have a method that will spawn isolate doing a heavy synchronous task which later the result being sent to the **main isolate** I would typically do this:

```
void isolatedWorker(Param param) {
  final result = <int>[];

  try {
    for (var x = 0; x < param.count; x++) {
      result.add(x);
    }
  } finally {
    param.sendPort.send(result);
    Isolate.current.kill();
  }
}
```

Will it be fine if I omit the line which kills the current isolate? assuming GC will take care of it?

Thanks in advance.